# Action Mailer Preview: Email 'new' not found in MessageMailerPreview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have three mailers, all of which work. But for one (the contact form) the mailer preview doesn't work and I don't understand why.

The error message:

```
undefined method 'email'
  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail from: message.email, subject: "Message from #{message.name}"
  end
```

In app/mailers/message_mailer.rb I have:

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default to: "<info@myemail.com>",
  return_path: "<info@myemail.com>"
  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail from: message.email, subject: "Message from #{message.name}"
  end
end
```

Part of app/views/messages/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :message, url: contact_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Your message…', class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

test/mailers/previews/test_mailer_preview.rb:

```
class MessageMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    message = [name: "My Name", email: "noreply@example.com", content: "This is my message"]
    MessageMailer.new_message(message)
  end
end
```

The contact form is properly working on the development server, and the other two mailers (password reset and authentication) also work and for these last two mailers the previews also work properly. These two mailers also have model.email in the mailer, and there it does work. I don't understand why the preview for the contact form mailer produces the error message.

Comment: just making sure the obvious here, but can you post the class declaration on your `MessageMailer`?

Comment: I've added them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out that if I replaced 
`message = [name: 'My Name', email: 'noreply@example.com', content: 'This is my message']`

with

```
message = Message.first
message.email = "example@example.com"
```

or even just

```
message = Message.first
```

the preview does work. Don't understand why since I would expect the original formulation also to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your mailer class isn't inherited from `ActionMailer`, which is fine if you have an ApplicationMailer class doing that already, can you post the code for it please? Otherwise try this.

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to find the code you're asking for (if you could specify, I'll post it). I changed the first line of `app/mailers/message_mailer.rb` to `class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base` but the result of the preview remained the same. Just to make sure: the mailer works fine on the server, it's just the preview that isn't working. I also have a second mailer (developed following the steps of Hartl's Rails tutorial) and that mailer preview does work fine. The setup of that preview looks the same to me. I've added it to my question.